# Confused about creating objects and using its methods

Tags: java

I'm beginner in object oriented programming and I need few answers to clear something up. I have a MainActivity and few classes for different operations. For example, in MainActivity I create an object with name mBluetoothReceiver from BluetoothReceiver class. There are methods for establish and manage BT connection, like sendData for example. In class Nmea I got some methods that uses methods from BluetoothReceiver, so for that reason I pass through constructor mBluetoothReceiver.

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BluetoothService mBluetoothService = new BluetoothService(this);

    //create new object from Nmea class and pass mBluetoothService to mNmea
    Nmea mNmea = new Nmea(mBluetoothService);
}
```

Nmea class:

```
public class Nmea {

BluetoothService mBluetoothService;

    //constructor for Nmea for BluetoothServce object
    public Nmea(BluetoothService bluetoothService) {
        mBluetoothService = bluetoothService;
    }

    public Nmea()
    {
    //empty constructor {

    }

    //Nmea methods...
}
```

My problem is, that I have also class GPS, which will also uses a methods from Nmea class, but I don't know how to do that. It's ok to put empty constructor in Nmea class and create Nmea object in GPS class? Bluetooth probably won't work if I don't pass BluetoothService object in? In class GPS I can't create new BluetoothService connection object and pass it to Nmea constructor, because I need only one established connection in whole project.

GPS class:

```
public çlass GPS {

Nmea gpsNmea = new Nmea();

//I need to use Nmea methods here

}
```

I hope you understand my question. What is good pratice with this stuff to get work it?
Thanks!

Comment: If your methods are public you can access it using dot notation! gpsNmea.yourMethod(); If you do not specify any modifier you'll get default modifier (public for the all element in your package. private for the element in other packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    BluetoothService mBluetoothService = new BlueToothService(this);

    Nmea mNmea = new Nmea(mBluetoothService);

    Gps mGps = new Gps(mNmea);     
}
```

And your `Gps` cconstructor need to look something like this:

```
public class Gps {

    private Nmea mNmea;

    public Gps(Nmea nmea) {
        mNmea = nmea;
    }
}
```

If you need to have only one instance of `BluetoothService` class you need to write him using [Singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and all needing methods in `Nmea` class declare as `public`

Comment: In that example that you wrote, it will be only one BluetoothService instance, right? I think that's the best and logic solution for me..

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing a Class method**

Depending on a methods `access modifier`, you can get to a method by using the `.` operator. Like so:

```
String s = "Hello";
s = s.substring(0,3); // See how you use the ".", then the name of the method.
```

**Your other queries**

> It's ok to put empty constructor in Nmea class and create Nmea object in GPS class?

There is no value to that. Java will provide a `default constructor` if you don't write one explicitly.

> In class GPS I can't create new BluetoothService connection object and pass it to Nmea constructor, because I need only one established connection in whole project.

Then you need to turn the class that handles the `BluetoothService` object into a singleton. You can read about singletons [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). With the singleton pattern, you can statically access the object, without consistently creating a new one.

**For example**

```
public abstract class BluetoothSingleton
{
    private static BluetoothService instance;
    // The one instance of BluetoohService that will be created.

    public static BluetoothService getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            // If an object doesn't currently exist.
            instance = new BluetoothService(); // or whatever you're using.
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then when you wish to obtain the `BluetoothService` object, simply call the `getInstance()` method in the `BluetoothSingleton` class.

```
BluetoothService = BluetoothSingleton.getInstance();
// This code will return the exact same instance. Only one will ever be created.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an instance of `Nmea` class inside `GPS` to use methods of `Nmea`. Just add this to your code`gpsNmea.any_Nmea_function()` inside `GPS` class eg:

```
public çlass GPS {

Nmea gpsNmea = new Nmea();

gpsNmea.getN(); //assuming getN() is a function defined in Nmea class.

}
```

The `.` operator allows you to access the member methods,or variables for a class instance variable.